# rsync: --no-whole-file does not work if a line added to file's tail

Tags: rsync

My question is related to [why rsync does not do delta transfer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/291156/198423) question.

First I create a 1GB file and transfer into `/target` folder using rsync. Later I added s `doo` string to the tail of that file. When I transfer the same file into `/target` folder, I observe that complete file has been transferred instead of transferring only its updated section.

**[Q]** How could I force rsync to do delta transfer only the updated section of the file? Is is possible or my only option is to transfer complete file all over again?

**Example:**

```
$ mkdir target
$ fallocate -l 1G target/temp_1GB_file
$ rsync --inplace --no-whole-file  --size-only --progress temp_1GB_file doo
temp_10GB_file
  1073741824 100%  227.30MB/s    0:00:04 (xfer#1, to-check=0/1)

sent 131163 bytes  received 229425 bytes  48078.40 bytes/sec
total size is 1073741824  speedup is 2977.75

$ echo 'doo' >> temp_10GB_file
$ rsync --no-whole-file  --size-only --progress temp_1GB_file doo # Here complete file has been transferred all over again.
  temp_10GB_file
  1073741828 100%  226.44MB/s    0:00:04 (xfer#1, to-check=0/1)

sent 131171 bytes  received 229418 bytes  48078.53 bytes/sec
total size is 1073741828  speedup is 2977.74
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't transfer the whole file:

```
sent 131171 bytes  received 229418 bytes  48078.53 bytes/sec
total size is 1073741828  speedup is 2977.74
```

The verbose output shows that only a part of the file was ever transferred in the second call to `rsync`.

`rsync` starts a sub-process for the sender and one for the receiver, and these sends checksums and data back and forth between themselves.

`rsync` checksums *blocks* of the file. By default, the block size depends on the file size.  If a checksum for a block mismatches between sender and receiver, the whole block is transferred.  The last block was modified by adding a string, so that had to be transferred.  This is why you see 131171 bytes being transferred rather than just the number of bytes actually changed in the file (the block size is around 130 KB for this particular file).

See also the `-B` option in the `rsync` manual.

Comment: But if I transfer exactly same file again,  verbose output is `sent 36 bytes  received 20 bytes  112.00 bytes/sec
total size is 46080006  speedup is 822857.25` where 36 bytes much less than 131171 bytes. But why adding `doo` to tail of the file cause 131171 bytes of transfer?  @Kusalananda

Comment: @Alper `rsync` does not compare the files byte by byte (which would require sending the whole file), but in blocks of some size. If the checksum for a block has a mismatch, the block is transferred.

Comment: Got it. Than probably block size is around 131171 bytes. @Kusalananda

Comment: @Alper See the `-B` option in the `rsync` manual :-)

Comment: @Alper Updated the answer. It's hopefully clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't transfer the whole file, but both the source and destination were read in their entirety to determine the differences.

With `--no-whole-file` you traded a simple "replace the file by copying it in its entirety" with a more complex "read the source and calculate its checksums; read the destination and calculate its checksums; update the differences".

On one system I have here it took longer to perform the second operation than just overwriting with the original. (Timings have a variance of about +/- 3 seconds over several attempts.)

- 29 seconds to copy the original
- 28 seconds to copy the updated original with the default `--whole-file`
- 59 seconds to compare and copy the updated original with `--no-whole-file`

There are (good) reasons why `rsync` sometimes does not use the delta transfer algorithm.